# Calculate time difference between two datetime in double digit hour,minutes and seconds format

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I am calculating time difference between two dates with format:

> Hour:Minutes:Seconds

Right now i am getting output like this with the following input:

```
StartDate=2016-06-29 15:52:32.360

EndDate=2016-06-29 15:52:36.970

Output:  0 : 0 : 4
```

But i want to get double digit output in time :

```
Expected Output: 00 : 00 : 04
```

**Input:**

```
StartDate=2016-06-29 15:52:32.360

EndDate=2016-06-29 15:53:36.970

Expected output: 00 : 01 : 04
```

This is my code:

```
public class Attendance
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }
}


var query = (from t in context.Attendance
             select new 
             {
             TotalTime =SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s",t.StartDateTime,t.EndDateTime) /3600 + " : "
            + SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) % 3600 / 60
            + ": " + SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) % 60,
              }).tolist();
```

**Note**:I dont want to do like below:

```
var query = (from t in context.Attendance.toList().
                  select new 
                  {
                     //code to calculate time difference and format time
                  }).tolist();
```

Comment: Subtracting one DateTime from another returns a TimeSpan. Just do the subtraction and formatting on the client

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos:is this what you are saying:t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value)???

Comment: (datetime-datetime).tostring()

Comment: Also note that EF is an ORM ie object-to-relational mapper, not a replacement for SQL. No objects or mapping are involved in this case. Whenever you see SQL concepts like joins or DateDiff leak into the ORM query, it's a strong indication that something is wrong

Comment: You can use `-` between DateTime values as well. Of course, a get-only property that calculates the difference would be even better and reduce the clutter

Comment: @Thomas :Can you please tell me how this string.format would work when this query will be converted in to equivalent sql query.Please before saying that this is duplicate question please read and understand question carefully

Comment: @Learning *don't* do this in the query. Add a simple property that returns the Timespan difference

Comment: @Mikolaytis:Tostring will work when this query will be converted in to equivalent sql query??

Comment: Hey, why not "simply" use `select new { TotalTime =(SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s",t.StartDateTime,t.EndDateTime) /3600).ToString("00") + " : " + (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) % 3600 / 60).ToString("00") + ": " + (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) % 60).ToString("00") }` and not actually "learning" about `TimeSpan` or `string` formatting...

Comment: @Corak:Tostring will not work.

Comment: Sorry, I meant of course: `select new { TotalTime = ((SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s",t.StartDateTime,t.EndDateTime) /3600) ?? 0).ToString("00") + " : " + ((SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) % 3600 / 60) ?? 0).ToString("00") + ": " + ((SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime) % 60) ?? 0).ToString("00") }`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, EF deals with objects, it isn't a replacement for SQL queries. You can easily add a read-only property that calculates the difference between the two values, and returns whatever you want if either of them is null, eg:

```
public partial class Attendance
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
  public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }

  public TimeSpan Duration 
  { 
       get 
       { 
           if (StartDateTime.HasValue && EndDateTime.HasValue)
           {
               return (EndDateTime.Value - StartDateTime.Value);
           }
           else {...}
       }
}
```

One you have the TimeSpan value you can format it using String.Format as the other answers show. In fact, formatting should be done as late as possible, preferably using a format string on the client or HTML view, to avoid mixing up client/server locales or having to parse the string back to a Timespan for farther processing

TimeSpan values can be formatted using either a [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx) or [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) format string, eg:

```
  var label=attendee.Duration.ToString("c");
```

Will generate a string in the form `[-][d'.']hh':'mm':'ss['.'fffffff]`. If the duration doesn't contain a date or millisecond component, this will match the format you want.

Serializing this class to Json doesn't need any formatting at all, since Json.NET can serialize TimeSpan to the `HH:mm:ss` format, as shown in [this example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm)

Comment: This is my data model generated using Database first(.edmx) in which it is written that Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.

Comment: No it won't, that's a basic feature of all generated classes in Visual Studio. The classes are *partial* so you can define other files with extra properties, methods etc that won't be overwritten. In fact, you'll notice that your class definition already includes the `partial` keyword

Comment: Ok i understand this so i should format this timespan object i.e Duration  in my query with string.format??

Comment: How this .Tostring Function will work inside this linq query??

Comment: No, you should do that on the form, window or view where you want to use that value. Preferably using the format string attribute of most desktop or web controls. Otherwise you will find at least one case where you have to parse the string back into a TimeSpan for processing, comparison, ordering.

Comment: actually i am returning this as json object to ajax get call so i should do this formatting there??

Comment: You don't do that in the query. Formatting in the query is a bad design, whether you do this writing raw T-SQL or in a LINQ statement. Fromatting should be done on the *client* side. Whatever rendering technology you use (web form, WPF, report rendering) all support field formatting of timespans. None of them support reformating of strings that look like timestamps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116473/discussion-between-learning-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Json.NET already serializes TimeSpan values. You don't need to format the value

Comment: I am using angular js as client side so i  was having a little hardtime calculating datetime difference and formatting as per my requirement that is why i am doing this in query but you a good point regarding user locales